# Why is this column ambigous while another column in the same table is not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to join 3 tables together and the third table I'm bringing in only has two columns.
1. AccountNo
2. AccountDescription

the 2nd has no red line underneath it in the select statement while accountNo does? Why is this my join statement looks fine

```
USE AP

SELECT VendorName, VendorState, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, AccountNo, 
InvoiceLineItemDescription, AccountDescription
FROM Vendors 
    JOIN Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
    JOIN GLAccounts ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
ORDER BY VendorState
```

The InvoiceLineItems table has the accountNo key so what's the issue?

Comment: Add proper aliases to your query and the problem should go away.

Comment: "The InvoiceLineItems table has the accountNo key so what's the issue?" - GLAccounts clearly also has a column of the same name hence the ambiguity

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both `InvoiceLineItems` and `GLAccounts` tables have a column `AccountNo`, but in the select you don't specify which one you want.

Change the select to:

```
SELECT
  VendorName, VendorState, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal,
  InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo, -- You must qualify ambiguous columns
  InvoiceLineItemDescription, AccountDescription
```